# How to Repaint Microsoft Chart in Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access, mschart

I have a **subform** which sets the RowSource of a Microsoft Chart 5.0 object in its **parent** form.

EDIT: The Row Source Type for the graph is Value List.

The graph does not paint itself, however, but any action which would generally generate a repaint (drag another Access window over it, minimize it, loss and regain of focus sometimes) does indeed repaint it. In other words, the graph doesn't show or change automatically.

How do I force a repaint of the chart after a subform action?

These have had no effect:

```
parent.Referesh
parent.Repaint
parent.TheChart.Refresh
```

And this does not seem to exist, unfortunately:

```
parent.TheChart.Repaint
```

Using: Access 2003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the repainting of the graph. Most likely, the subform that you are using is retrieving data from a query or table.

You must update the values on the "datasource" object, which is providing the subform data (either a query or a table). Then, re-query the graph object in the mainform.

I made a very simple example in my MS-Acess 2000 and it worked great:

- A table (`t01_fruits`) with three columns (`frt_id`, `frt_name`, `frt_qty`).
- A subform based in the t01 table.
- A mainform with the previous subform inside, a pie-chart based on table `t01_fruits` and a button. In the `OnClick` event of the button, I put just `me.graph1.requery`.

When I update the fruits quantity in subform, inside mainform, nothing happens with the graph. When I click the button, the graph is updated correctly.

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer. That makes sense. I should mention that my button is in the subform. Terrible design, I know. Do you know if there is a way to have the parent form graph display properly on an event in a subform?

Comment: Yes, I do. Isn't the best way but, come on, we don't need a nuke blast to kill rats, do we?

Comment: Supose you have a button in the subform. Add to OnClick event of the button the line `Forms!form1!graph1.requery` where "form1" is your mainform and "graph1" is your graph control. You should add this line to any event in the subform. It works even with unnested forms, since they're open. It works well with reports too (`reports!report1!textbox1`)

Comment: Good idea, but no dice. The `RowSource` is not from a table, it's `RowSourceType` is a `Value List`. That might have an incidence...

Comment: Well, have you tried to do the task with the graph inside the subform? I don't know if is possible generate graphs on value lists... Consider another approach, like working with a table as datasource for the graph. Maybe it would be faster.

Comment: @darth_alexious: I've set the graph to use a query as datasource, I've set the triggering button in the parent form, and the behaviour is still the same. My newest theory is that I have something else that's preventing the graph from displaying right in the first place, but I'm not sure what...

Comment: Doesn't the graphic update even when you requery the source query? It's very strange. Would you post some portions of the code to provide more information?

Comment: I'm going to make a sample project from scratch, see if it works. There's very little priority put on this now, so it's purely a curiosity at this point. That means it might take a while before I have the time to make this.

Comment: Ok, you can send me the sample when you do it, I'm curious too. Good luck.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer for "most similar cases". I no longer have access to the code base as I have changed jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem in refreshing chart after updating information in form. I got it resolved by re-queering the chart after update of the inbox linking to change of data.

```
 Private Sub txtFinAgreeEnacDt_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.graphCRMStatus.Requery
 end sub  


 Private Sub txtFinAgreeEnacDt_AfterUpdate()
     Me.Requery
 End Sub
```

Me is the Form holding graph....

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem like this, having main page with sub-forms, including 2 with graphs - and solution to refresh it was like this:

```
me.subForm.Requery
me.subForm!Graph1.Requery
```

Only when you execute commands in this order, it would update graph properly.

I know it's been a while since question was asked, but in case anyone else has issue like this.

Comment: Hi, you should file a new question for that